# Java String split with multicharacter delimiter

Tags: java, string, split, character

I'm fairly new to Java and I thought this worked the same as with other languages.

For a string:

```
String line = "3::Daniel::Louis||##2::Leon: the Professional::1994||6::Jean::Reno||7::Gary::Oldman||8::Natalie::Portman||##3::Scarface::1983||9::Al::Pacino||10::Michelle::Pfeiffer";
```

I want to split it at every `||##`.

But:

```
for(String s : line.split("||##")) {
    System.out.println("|"+s+"|");
 }
```

returns:

```
||
|3|
|:|
|:|
|D|
|a|
|n|
|i|
```

... etc.

I was expecting:

```
3::Daniel::Louis

Leon: the Professional
```

... etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PS: Are Abel Ferrara's "King of New York" or Walter Hill's "Streets of Fire" in the list ;)?

Comment: ha ha ha, just random stuff i got from imdb's top 200 list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to escape the | character since it's a regex metacharacter for logical OR

So I would use

```
line.split("\\|\\|##"))
```

Note that You have to escape the slash as well that is why I use

```
\\|
```

instead of

```
\|
```

To escape that metacharacter

Comment: Nitpick: What it is in Java itself doesn't matter one bit.  But it's also an "or" in the syntax of regular expressions, which have a whole separate language of their own.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Comment: Sweet dumb me! you are all right and yes, it's got nothing to do with Java but RegEx. thank you all, got to give credit to the first poster that worked though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|\\|##", Pattern.LITERAL)  
String[] result = p.split(myString)
```

I know you can have multiple characters in your delimiter, and that you can *exclude* your delimiter from the output string.

I *don't* know if the example above will work *exactly* for your scenario; you might have to experiment a bit (for example, "escaping" regex "metacharacters" with "\").

Here's the Javadoc for Pattern.compile:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

And here's more information on Java regex syntax:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the bars: `|` is a special character in the regex.

Use:

```
for(String s : line.split("\\|\\|##")) {
```

Alternately, you can use `\Q\E` to force that the entire pattern be used literally:

```
for(String s : line.split("\\Q||##\\E")) {
```

This is probably the same pattern that you'll get from [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

`|` allows you to specify optional patterns in a regex. Your regex is equivalent to `|##`, or: *nothing **OR** ##*. This splits around the empty string, or between every character in the input.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for `Pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your `|` characters:

```
for (String s : line.split("\\|\\|##"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the '|' like this \|

Answer (score 0):

Gilberto's solution will work just fine in this case, but you might want to check out [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).  It has a lot of very useful utility classes including a String splitter.  With it you could write:

```
Iterable<String> frags = Splitter.on("||##").split(line);
// Do whatever with the iterable...maybe you just want a list?
// List<String> fragList = Lists.newArrayList(frags);
```

Comment: I used Guava last month for an Android app, needed to move a large database from the bundle to the data folder, but other than that I'm pretty new to it and haven't looked at all the functionality it contains. thanks for the advice though